# Restrict fat16 Veracrypt volume to single user on MacOS

Tags: macos, permission, encryption, mount

I am trying to mount a fat16 Veracrypt volume on a multi-user MacOS system.
The mounted volume always seems to allow full permissions for **all users** on the system.
I have tried everything I can think of to restrict to **only the current user** via `diskutil` command, `chmod`, `chown` of mount point, etc but have been unsuccessful.

How can I secure the mounted volume?

Ideally, I'd like something permanent that doesn't mess with the files inside the volume or require special action every time the volume is mounted.

Comment: What exactly have you tried in terms of commands? Isn't there an option in the Veracrypt application for this?

Comment: @nohillside `diskutil mount -mountPoint ~/vc /dev/disk2` where `vc` has mod 700, or is owned by root, etc.  `mount -t fat16` doesn't seem to be supported as a FS type.

Comment: `mount -t msdos -m 0700` maybe?

Comment: @nohillside On mac, there is no `mount -m` option, but `mount_msdos -m 0700` mounts, and shows expected permissions `drwx------@   1 jc`, but if I login as a different user (eg `foo`), they see all of the files and permissions are `drwx------@   1 foo`

Comment: I was able to mount an APFS volume which properly respects ownership using `mount_apfs -u jc /dev/disk2 ~/vc` -- I guess it is a problem with msdos volumes only?